# Fuse DetailView and FormView

Tags: python, django

I want to create a Twitter-like list of posts/entries below a form (`Create` from CRUD). Something like this [crude representation](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmzaL).

In Django, can I create a `View` class that can have the following?

- A template
- A form
- A list of objects

I know of `DetailView` (which can also have a template, like `TemplateView`) and `FormView`, but I don't know of anything that may have both functionalities.

Which is the proper approach, use some built-in class, build a new class, or simply override the `get_context_data` function as a return a `objects` list which contains `Model.entries.all()`?

Bear in mind I have little to no idea about CRUD views and Forms alike, but I can handle myself around the base `TemplateView`, it's methods and properties, and the Django template syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up overloading class, as similar to ListView as possible:

```
class ListCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', ]
    template_name = 'my_template.html'
    success_url = '/success/'
    context_object_name = 'objects'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context[self.context_object_name] = self.model.objects.all()

        return context
```